# How to import the same Excel file into SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I had created an asp.net mvc4 application and I deployed it to the web.

In this application I have a controller to import some Excel file into the database.

On my localhost it's working fine, but on the server when I try to import a file that has the same name as an existing file it gives me an error

(I can't see the exception I see just some nice message (catch .....)

This  is  a part of code :

```
if (Request.Files["file"].ContentLength > 0)
{
    string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["file"].FileName);

    if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
    {
        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/") + Request.Files["file"].FileName;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
        }

        Request.Files["file"].SaveAs(fileLocation);

        string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;

        excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
        fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";

        //connection String for xls file format.
        if (fileExtension == ".xls")
        {
            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
            fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        //connection String for xlsx file format.
        else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
        {
            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
            fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }

        //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
        excelConnection.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        if (dt == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        int t = 0;

        //excel data saves in temp file here.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            t++;
        }

        OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

        string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);

        using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
        {
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        }

        excelConnection.Close();
    }

    if (fileExtension.ToString().ToLower().Equals(".xml"))
    {
        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/") + Request.Files["FileUpload"].FileName;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
        }

        Request.Files["FileUpload"].SaveAs(fileLocation);
        XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(fileLocation);

        ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
        xmlreader.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer comes without knowledge of the specific exception (as you mentioned, you can't see the exception yourself). In my similar experience, I've run across the same problem, and it was resolved by installing the Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 driver on the server. I've installed the following component to resolve the problem:

2007 Office System Driver - Data Connectivity Components:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

If that doesn't help, more information regarding the exception you're seeing would be helpful in solving the problem.

Comment: think  you   i  will  make a return  to   tell you  if  that  is  worked   but  i  think  is  the  best answer  !!